# passing a parameter and other props to a component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{cartItems.map((item, pos) =>{
    return (
        <div className="item-container" key ={pos}>
            <Item {...item } setIsLoading={setIsLoading}  />
        </div>
    )
})}
```

when I try to call setIsLoading in Item, it gives me an error saying that

> "Uncaught TypeError: setIsLoading is not a function"

I am also not very sure if the header was written correctly:

```
const Item = (product, setIsLoading) => {
    //....
    setIsLoading(true);
}
```

it was working fine before I added setIsLoading. I am a bit confused about what the problem is.

Comment: You need to destructure the arguments i.e. `const Item = ({setIsLoading, ...product}) => {`

Comment: but how come the argument doesn't need to be destructured if it only contains product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props in a component is only an object
You can see the documentation [here](https://www.linkedin.com/in/saulrmoreyra/)

But for now you can destructure the props

```
const Item = ({setIsLoading, ...product}) => {
    //....
    setIsLoading(true);
}
```